# Unable to save image to database and folder using Slim Framework

Tags: php, slim

I am very new to PHP, I am using PHP Slim Framework. I have tried to research through Stack Overflow but didn't find an answer that answered my question.

I am trying add a car description on my school project, it captures all the fields well but the image is not being saved to the database and not being uploaded to the images folder, instead it saves the image in the database as a json as:

```
{
    "car_images":
    [
        {
            "file":"C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php8F2B.tmp"
        }
    ]
}
```

instead of *a91cffe8c9b5082f.jpg*.

when I try to view the image in a browser on my localhost it goes to this path:

> http://localhost/carbac/public/category_image/%7B%22car_images%22:[%7B%22file%22:%22C://xampp//tmp//php8F2B.tmp%22%7D]%7D

What could I be doing wrong?

Below is my function for capturing the details:

```
public function add(Request $request, Response $response, $args){

    $car_category_id =  $request->getParam('car_category_id');
    $name =  $request->getParam('name');
    $description =  $request->getParam('description');
    $price = $request->getParam('price');
    $mileage =  $request->getParam('mileage');
    $fuel_type =  $request->getParam('fuel_type');
    $transmission =  $request->getParam('transmission');     
    $fuel_economy =  $request->getParam('fuel_economy');     
    $air_condition =  $request->getParam('air_condition');   
    $hourly_price =  $request->getParam('hourly_price');
    $daily_price =  $request->getParam('daily_price');  
    $year = $request->getParam('year');

    $directory = __DIR__ . '/../../../public/profile_image';

    $uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles()['category_image'];

    $avater = $request->getUploadedFiles();


    foreach($uploadedFiles as $uploadedFile) {
        if ($uploadedFile->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $avater[] = \App\Helpers\FileUpload::moveUploadedFile($directory, $uploadedFile, ['png', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'jpg']);
        } else {

            $Flash = new Flash();
            $Flash->addMessage('message', "Sorry, something went wrong from our end, please notify site owner");
            $Flash->addMessage('status', "callout-danger");

            return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('car_description'));
        }

    }
    if( ! $avater ) {

        $Flash = new Flash();
        $Flash->addMessage('message', "Sorry, Please make image you are uploading is either a 'png', 'jpeg' or 'gif'");
        $Flash->addMessage('status', "callout-danger");

        return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('car_description'));
    }

    $car_description = CarDescription::create([
        'car_category_id' => $car_category_id,
        'name' => $name,
        'description' => $description,
        'year' => $year,
        'mileage' => $mileage,
        'price' => $price,
        'fuel_type' => $fuel_type,
        'transmission' => $transmission,     
        'fuel_economy' => $fuel_economy,     
        'air_condition' => $air_condition,   
        'hourly_price' => $hourly_price,
        'daily_price' => $daily_price,
        'images' => json_encode($avater)
    ]);
```

Comment: Then why do you store some `json_encode`d stuff in your `images` key?

Comment: Any error messages in apache error log? + whats returned value of `var_dump($avater)` ?

Comment: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for `foreach`in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\carbac\\app\\src\\Action\\CarDescriptionAction.php on line 235, referer: http://localhost/carbac/public/car_description

Comment: Something is wrong with your `$uploadedFiles` var. Whats the output of `var_dump($uploadedFiles)`?

Comment: This is my error: The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:4497] AH00127: Cannot map GET /carbac/public/category_image/%7B%22car_images%22:[%7B%22file%22:%22C://xampp//tmp//php4B2B.tmp%22%7D]%7D HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://localhost/carbac/public/car_description